# How to configure a static website (only http) on GCP without a load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dns

I have a **very** simple website that I want to host in a GCP bucket. I want it to only use http (not https) and don't want to add a load balancer and most examples of static GCP websites show adding a load balancer.

The only example I could find without a load balancer shows pointing a CNAME record to c.storage.googleapis.com which would connect to the bucket that's named [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com).

So far, that works fine *except* that it doesn't include access to the domain without the www subdomain attached (mysite.com). And, I can't attach an ALIAS record that just points mysite.com to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) because Google Cloud DNS doesn't have ALIAS records.

It seems like there would be a pretty simple solution but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design you cannot create a CNAME record in a "root" domain level. It has to point to a subdomain. Unless you're pointing it to other domain.

By design buckets are served using `CNAME` record such as `www.mysite.com` pointing to `c.storage.googleapis.com`.

**So you're forced to use `www` prefix or other subdomains.**

There's a [mention in the documentation of a possibility to serve bucket using `A` record](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets#considerations).

> You can use a bucket name in a DNS record as part of a `CNAME` or `A` redirect which gave me an idea.

**But it's a "brittle and hardwired" solution**

You need to create bucket named "mysite.com" with the copy of your site.

Then you go to your managed zone and edit `A` record to point to the IP of `c.storage.googleapis.com` which is `74.125.143.128` (at least at the moment I was writing this). Next you change your CNAME record `www.mysite.com` to point to `mysite.com` to redirect `www` to non www.

Then wait until the changes propagate and you're set :) I tested it and it works. I don't like to wait so I changed TTL's of all records involved to 1 minute.

Then you'd ask yourself why I wrote it's "brittle and hardwired" ? It will work until someone will change the IP of `c.storage.googleapis.com`.
Maybe there is some other way to set up DNS records to point to c.storage.googleapis.com instead of IP but I wasn't able to figure this out.

If you don't change your CNAME record and leave it pointing to
`c.storage.googleapis.com` then you can have to sites (identical or not it's up to you). One available with `www` - other without.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. It seems a little sad that there isn't a more straight forward way to accomplish something seemingly so everyday.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation :) If my answer helped you in any way please accept it :)

Comment: Google Support mentioned another solution: Domain Forwarding is a feature of Google Domains and would do what I want. I'm currently using Namecheap as a registrar but I'm going to switch to Google Domains for this solution.

Comment: Google Support also mentioned that they are currently working on adding ALIAS records to Cloud DNS and that would actually be the best solution.